# Why is Path Analyzer not showing the same number of visits as Experience Analytics?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, path-analyzer

When I look at general site statistics in the Experience Analytics they seem to broadly match what our Google Analytics account tells us. But when I look in path analyzer, it seems to show far fewer visits, roughly 1/3 of what I'm seeing in the experience analytics page. This is problematic as it means path analyzer doesn't have enough data in some areas to show meaningful results.

PS - I am not a developer, I am a front-end user of the site.
PPS - I am fully prepared to accept I might just be using it wrong! 
[image: Experience Analytics visits]

[image: Path analyzer visits]